# How to reuse backup on Time Machine on Snow Leopard after a logic board change, after choosing wrong option on popup

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, backup, time-machine

After my logic board was replaced, I connected my laptop back to my network, and Time Machine gave me a popup, as shown on this thread:

[How to recycle/reuse/continue Time Machine for a new Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/78068/recycle-time-machine-for-new-machine/78264#78264)

I misread the question and clicked on "Create New Backup" when I should have clicked on "Reuse Backup" to connect to my old backup file. How can I trigger that popup again? Turning Time Machine on and off does not work, and the instructions on forums to fix via terminal doesn't work because snow leopard is missing the fsaclctl command (and I'm also not familiar with terminal commands.)

Thanks.

Comment: I could imagine it *might* show again when you delete the new backup. Can you hook up the disk, double click the orange disk icon (not a green one, if Time Machine happens to "mount" the backup itself), and tell us what directories you see? (A bit [like this](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2007/10/mac-os-x-10-5.ars/14#time-machine-internals).)

Comment: I deleted the new backup and it worked! The magic popup appeared, and this time I clicked on "Reuse Backup." I'm now reconnected to my old backup file. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Since Lion you can use `tmutil`:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/DISKNAME/Backups.backupdb/COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: When I enter this, it only says: `The image "<requested>.sparsebundle" can't be inherited because it would conflict with "<wrong>.sparsebundle".`

Answer (score -1):

Right-click (Ctrl-Click) Time Machine, and choose "Browse Other Time Machine Disks...". Select the disk, and select "Use Selected Disk".
(Note that you may have to mount your sparsebundle if you use Time Capsule)

Comment: Both the old and new backup are on the same disk. So, just to be sure: is that what you mean as well? (So, "Browse Other Time Machine Disks" would allow for selecting another backup folder from the same backup disk, and then "Use Selected Disk" makes TM use that specific backup folder for future backups? If that's what you're saying then this is indeed a very nice solution.)

Comment: This answer does not at all do what you want. It's just a way to browse time machine backups. I don't have the rep to downvote on this site, but this answer deserves to be downvoted.